# Pulling links into Chrome extension popup.html

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-chrome-extension

How do you go about pulling all links (hyper and text) from the page being viewed into popup.html once it is launched? I want to make these appear in a textbox within popup.html.

Comment: What element types are they? Are they all of type <a>?

Comment: They are not necessarily elemented (should work on most websites). Just looking for "Http://www" I think I probably have to scrap code from one of those link checker scripts.

Comment: If you're planning to do it that way, then a regular expression to get everything beginning with "http://www" is the way to go, then iterate through all the results from that and output them as links into your popup.html

Comment: I am more concerned of the process of getting it into the popup than finding them. Can you explain how this could be done (using the www method you mentioned)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wcKGg/

Comment: Hey thanks. It works but it grabs it from popup.html. I want it to grab from the chrome page the person is viewing and pull it into popup.html

Comment: You need to tell your regular expression to act on the html of the browser page, rather than the popup. The Chrome Extensions API and documentation should be able to help with that.

Comment: Yeah, its primarily the API send message found here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html I made a pastebin with what I have so far if you dont mind looking at it. Its the communication function that I cant get to work: http://pastebin.com/UxhJAdMb

Comment: This should return the current page source, you can perform your regex on it: `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   sendResponse(document.body.innerHTML);
});`